# How to enable local network users to access sites on apache macOS on different ports?

Tags: macos, apache

I wanna to see my apache webpages using IP:PORT addres (I use different ports and virtual hosts)  on devices connected to the same wifi network - how configure apache to allow this on macOS?

Here is my `httpd-vhost.conf` file header configuration:

```
<Directory "/Users/.../projects">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do it you must edit two files - first in `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` by adding line:

```
Listen 8082
```

Where 8082 is port of your website. And second file: `/etc/apache2/extras/httpd-vhosts.conf` add vhost similar to this:

```
<VirtualHost 192.168.8.101:8082>
  DocumentRoot "/Users/.../projects/my-project/public"
  ServerName my-project.localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

And reset apache (e.g by `sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl stop; sudo /usr/sbin/apachectl start`) Now, when you type `192.168.8.101:8082` in browsers in all your devices, you should see your webpage